# How to use composer, artisan ...(Laravel) php commands manually

Tags: php, laravel, ssh, composer-php, laravel-artisan

I have one problem I have no ssh access to the server, so I cannot use php artisan, composer and other commands.
As I can quess they do nothing other than modifying files or just copying php src files to specific directories.
In order to understand that process better and because of no access via ssh to the server I am looking for tutroial, manual or an article how can I perform this commands manually.
For example I need to execute

`php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWTAuthServiceProvider"`

What should I do in this case, it would be grate to find some document describes what should I do manually to get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel provides a handy Facade for artisan commands.

Just use `Artisan::call('your-command')` from where you need.

**Example:**

```
Route::get('artisan-command/{command}', function($command) {
    Artisan::call($command);
});
```

Your URL looks like this: `http://yourhost.com/artisan-command/db:seed`

**More specific for your use-case:**

```
Route::get('vendor-publish/{provider}', function($provider) {
    Artisan::call('vendor:publish', ['provider' => $provider]);
});
```

And the URL: `http://yourhost.com/vendor-publish/Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWTAuthServiceProvider`

Reference: [Artisan Console in the Laravel Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/artisan#calling-commands-via-code)

Comment: and how to run `php composer.phar require laravel/ui` ? is there any Composer::call or still using Artisan::call ?

Answer (score -1):

You can execute command lines from your app. You can do something like this:

```
Route::get('execute/my/command', function(){
    exec("php path/to/your/project/artisan your-command",$resultLines);
    Foreach($resultLines as $resultLine){
         echo $resultLine;
     }
});
```

First exec property is your command and second is variable to save the result.
I hope that help you

Comment: This is assuming 'exec' is enabled on the server. Given that the OP has no SSH access it seems unlikely.